# sh: 1: : Permission denied when launching buildscript

Tags: linux, debian, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I got this error when i launch my buildscript (dev) :

```
Checking for php executable..................... 
success [PHP 5.6.26-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Sep 21 2016 12:37:50)] 
Checking composer...................
sh: 1: : Permission denied
```

I just installed oh-my-zsh...

The owner of $HOME/.zsh, $HOME/.oh-my-zsh is my current user. Same for

```
/module/buildscripts/bin/build
```

who's the launched script.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried launch this script by sudo -u {userwithpermission}